# Connecting to a database with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I know how to establish a connection with a MySQL database with PHP, but I just have a simple question.

When you do this:

```
$connection= mysqli_connect(parameters);
```

is the connection established then, or when you do this:

```
mysqli_query($connect, other parameter);
```

I only ask because I am unsure, because when you set the $connection variable, aren't you also calling the mysqli_connect() function?

Comment: Nope. `mysqli_connect()` establishes the connection, and passes the connection resource to `$connection`. No further calls take place just because `$connection` is used

Comment: +you can verify this using an SQL monitor. @Pekka Why not write it as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

mysqli_connect()/new mysqli() establishes the connection and returns identifier and you cannot run a query before connecting.

Next time you could do some reseacrh - there is so much information on this topic.

Make sure youre aware of the [SO FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 0):

The connection is established when you call `$connection = mysqli_connect(parameters)` (Which is deprecated, you could simply use `$connection = new mysqli(parameters);`)

And it lasts until you close it with `mysqli_close()`

Comment: then what is the point of mysqli_query($connection, other param)?

Comment: You always need a valid connection resource to perform a query. In MySQL it doesn't seem like it, because if you don't specify one it uses the last resource created by a `mysql_connect()`. You could always use the object oriented approach and skip the link part.

Comment: @user1174762: mysqli_query() actually performs an SQL query. It uses a connection variable to determine which connection to use when making the query.